# svn strange tree conflit when a branch trying to merge from another branch using Intellij IDEA

Tags: svn, intellij-idea

There is a project A on the Trunk, and its two branches A1 and A2. Both A1 and A2 are under developing for a while.

Now I want to merge changes of A2 to A1. I am using Intellij IDEA's "merge from..." feature and set A2 a branch of A1's. However, after I selected which revisions to merge, and clicked ok, it comes "tree confilct" in src/main folder.

Does anyone have the same problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, it's possible
2. It doesn't correlate in any way with Intellij specially
3. While you don't show log of branches nobody can tell you more details

"Tree confict" error is ordinary case for Subversion, Subversion merge. It appear 100% on merge-trees, when in two future merge-sources,the **same file** (in different parts) is **changed and renamed**

In order to workaround: merge *conflicted files* (you'll see filename of file-in-question in temp-file name) and only after it - *parent dirs*